# Null Pointer Exception at calling postInvalidate method in thread class

Tags: android, multithreading, android-custom-view, invalidation

I have created custom `thread` and used `postInvalidate` method for recalling and move the image  but there is `Null Pointer Exception` at my `Thread class AnimThread for PostInvalidate` .

```
package com.example.ahmad.ballmoving;
    import android.view.View;
    /**
     * Created by Ahmad on 7/30/2015.
     */
    public class AnimThread extends Thread {
        private View threadView;
        public AnimThread(View view )
        {
            if(view!=null) {
                threadView = view;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    threadView.postInvalidate();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

***This is my Custom view Class .***

```
    package com.example.ahmad.ballmoving;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.View;

    /**
     * Created by Ahmad on 7/29/2015.
     */
    public class MyContextView extends View
    {
        int xVelocity=1;
        int yVelocity=1;
        private Runnable runn;
        Bitmap imag1;
        int x=0,y=0;

        public MyContextView(Context context, AttributeSet att)
        {
            super(context);
  imag1=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.images);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            super.onDraw(canvas);

            x=x+xVelocity;
            y=y+yVelocity;
           //canvas.save();
            //invalidate();
            canvas.drawBitmap(imag1, x, y, null);

        }
    }
```

***This is my Main Class***

```
package com.example.ahmad.ballmoving;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        private Thread thread1;
        private Thread thread2;
        public MyContextView mcv;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            MyContextView c = (MyContextView)findViewById(R.id.ko);
            Thread a = new AnimThread(c);
            a.start();
        } 
    }
```

***This is my XML of Main Class :***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.ahmad.ballmoving.MyContextView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ko"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the logs of the error ? You code looks right...

Comment: are u asking for logcat ??

Comment: 08-03 04:05:13.121    1959-1975/com.example.ahmad.ballmoving E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-60
    Process: com.example.ahmad.ballmoving, PID: 1959
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.ahmad.ballmoving.AnimThread.run(AnimThread.java:23)

Comment: are you sure that `(MyContextView)findViewById(R.id.ko);` does not return `null` ? Can you add a test for that ?

Comment: It is returning null .. Why it is returning null ? The View obtained in AnimThread Class gets null view in constructor When I debug it .

Comment: Maybe your not setting the right layout in the `setContentView` method. Are you sure the `activity_main.xml` is tehe file you show us (in the running configuration) ?

Comment: yes,activity_main.xml is the file that show (in the running configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try **CountDownTimer** ?

```
new CountDownTimer(1000,100) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            threadView.postInvalidate();

        }
    }.start();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks.. But I will get these errors after using CountdownTimer:  at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:109)
            at android.os.CountDownTimer.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:109)
            at com.example.ahmad.ballmoving.AnimThread$1.<init>(AnimThread.java:26)
            at com.example.ahmad.ballmoving.AnimThread.run(AnimThread.java:25)

Comment: @AhmadIrfan, no need to write Thread a = new AnimThread(c);
            a.start();.

Comment: Thread a = new AnimThread(c); a.start(); That code is for movement of image . If I remove it .The image do not move .It remains static

Comment: @AhmadIrfan, You did only postValidate of view in thread so you can do this animation on UIThread.